# Android fail to change state statelistdrawable

Tags: android, drawable, state

I've a custom drawable I'm using as background for one of my layout.

My drawable :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
<item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/red" android:endColor="@color/red" android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And this is my layout :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="call" >
```

When programmatically I set :

```
    btn.setEnabled(false);
```

The background of my btn stays with the same color. It doesn't become red, why ?

Comment: try adding a default item(i.e. one without the state attribute) as well in the selector.

Comment: mhh, but I want by default I've a green background, and I want to set red color just when I need to do it.

Comment: yes that's exactly what a default item is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.You can either use gradient or color for each states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/red" android:startColor="@color/red" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false"><shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/grey" android:startColor="@color/grey" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"><shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/green" android:startColor="@color/green" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: No, i want to define the color on my shape.

Comment: it will work. place your <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/red" android:endColor="@color/red" android:angle="270" />
    </shape> code inside item

Comment: it's exactly what I did ^^

Comment: this code worked ? try to use state enabled and state disabled, with a default case.

Comment: then add a default state with some color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63017/discussion-between-ashwin-s-ashok-and-develost).